# windows azure cloud platform mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My application is on windows azure, 
some days back i got break in my app.
following event viewer log i got,

```
User name: ; 
User ID: ; 
Message: Error in ExecuteCore Of Basecontroller actionName: common controller: admin; 
Exception: A public action method 'common' was not found on controller 
xyz.Web.Controllers.AdminController'.; 
StackTrace:    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at xyz.Web.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore(); 
Source application: System.Web.Mvc;
```

what is the reason, and how to prevent this?

plz help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to link to the common method in the Admin controller. Either verify that it exists and is working correctly, or remove the links to that action.